# Detect if mouse has left Pygame window

Tags: python, pygame, mouse

I'm writing a small Pygame script and I need to know if the mouse has left the Pygame window

I don't know how else to explain it. It seems simple, but I can't find a solution anywhere.

Comment: have you try event `pygame.MOUSEMOTION` with `event.pos` ?

Comment: @furas MOUSEMOTION won't tell me if its *out* of the screen (nagative values), but it seems to always capture 0s which means it probably also catches maxes... if it reliably reports the extreme edges, I could use that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`pygame.mouse.focus()` gives `0` when mouse leaves window (at least in Linux)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import pygame

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))

is_running = True
while is_running:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            is_running = False
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                is_running = False

    print(pygame.mouse.get_focused())

pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand why there is no one tell you to use ACTIVEEVENT.

I don't know in older pygame version, but in windows 10, python 3.7.3, pygame 1.9.6, I can use this:

```
import pygame as pg
video = pg.display.set_mode((300,300))

running = True

while running:
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if (event.type == pg.ACTIVEEVENT):
            if (event.gain == 1):  # mouse enter the window
                print("Welcome, cursor! :D   ",
                      "Selamat datang, kursor! :D")
            else:  # mouse leave the window
                print("Good bye, cursor! :(  ",
                      "Sampai jumpa, kursor! :(")
        elif (event.type == pg.QUIT):
            running = False
            pg.display.quit()
            print("Bye! Have a nice day! ",
                  "Sampai jumpa! Semoga harimu menyenangkan! :)")
```

I've tested it. It works!

Answer (score 0):

I did some testing...

```
if not bool(game.mouse.get_focused()):
    print("Mouse has left (Method 1)")
```

and...

```
elif event.type == game.MOUSEMOTION:
    checkFocus(event, self.canvas)

def checkFocus(e, display):
    x, y = e.pos
    MX, MY = display.get_size()
    MX -= 1 # 0 - based
    MY -= 1
    if x <= 0 or y <= 0 or x >= MX or y >= MY:
        print("Mouse has left (Method 2)")
```

and method 1 worked all of the time while method 2 only worked most of the time (Particularly around the max X and Ys [MX & MY])

Here's an actual log of me swinging my mouse around like a maniac...

```
Mouse has left (Method 1)
Mouse has left (Method 2)
Mouse has left (Method 1) <--
Mouse has left (Method 1) <--
Mouse has left (Method 2)
Mouse has left (Method 1)
```

As you can see, in just this short sample, method 1 works more often than method two.

Thank you to everyone who helped out!

Comment: Tested WIN10 by the way, so it isn't just a Linux thing